# Terminal communication with serial devices with libreadline / history support

Tags: linux, terminal-emulator

Is there a Linux terminal emulator (to communicate with a GPS logger device) with lib readline support, especially command history by pressing ctrl+R like in bash?

Would be nice if it is in Ubuntu's package sources.

Answer (score 4):

`socat` has an option to use the gnu readline library on an input. Eg

```
socat READLINE,history=$HOME/.cmd_history /dev/ttyS0,b19200,raw,echo=0,crnl
```

This no longer works on Ubuntu and Debian due to licensing incompatibilities.

An alternative readline front-end to any command is `rlwrap`, which is available on Ubuntu.

Comment: $ socat READLINE,history=$HOME/.cmd_history    /dev/ttyS0,b19200,raw,echo=0,crnl
2016/11/23 22:02:23 socat[5075] E unknown device/address "READLINE"

Comment: See my update for `rlwrap` instead.